# how to implement next-auth for external API login in Next 13 appDir

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

Hi I am trying to implement a login with next-auth in next 13 has `appDir: true` and the version of next is 13.3.0 but I checked the documentation but the truth is I don't understand, I am doing it with typescript but there is almost no documentation and I don't know if I am doing it right.

app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { username, password } = credentials as { username: string; password: string };
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
        });
        const user = await res.json();
        if (res.ok) {
          return user;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt"
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

layout.tsx

```
'use client'

import './globals.css'
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"


export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <SessionProvider>
          {children}
        </SessionProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

when I add the `<SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>` I get the following error and it does not load the pages.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

app/api/auth/[... nextauth]/route.ts

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  role: string;
  created_at: string;
  updated_at?: any;
  iat: number;
  exp: number;
  jti: string;
}

const handler = NextAuth({
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const { email, password } = credentials as {
          email: string;
          password: string;
        };
        const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/login", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
        });
        // tipar peticion de user
        const user = await res.json();
        if (res.ok && user) {
          // mostrar el encabezado de autorización en la consola
          return user;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
      if (user) token = user as unknown as { [key: string]: any };
      console.log(token);
      
      return token;
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      session.user = { ...token }
      return session;
    },
  },
  secret: "supersecret",
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

[image]

app/Providers.tsx

```
'use client'

import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"


interface Props {
    children: ReactNode
}

function Providers({ children }: Props) {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>
}

export default Providers;
```

layout.tsx

```
import { ReactNode } from 'react'
import './globals.css'
import Provider from './Providers'

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }: Props) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="author" content="Vercel" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.lineicons.com/4.0/lineicons.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <Provider>{children}</Provider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

and when sending the credentials, the same credentials and data are sent.

Comment: Very nice thank you so much, when the user object is too large you will have a large jwt token too. I think also that the "token" property is misleading its actually the tokenPayload we are setting here..

Answer (score 0):

### First

It looks like this is [under development](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/tree/5f1b75a7a2396ab34b171c951b96706417681f5c/apps/dev/nextjs-v4) still.

You can follow this repository for the latest changes. I will update this answer once there is a working example.

### Second

It could be that your `await fetch(...)` call is returning a `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error` code, and returns an error page, which is an invalid JSON document, instead.

Add a `console.log(await res.text())` instead of `const user = await res.json()` to verify this.

Comment: I already solved it was the update of next 13.3.0 is solved by first creating the function and after creating it export it hopefully and solve it.

Comment: here's how to use next-auth in next 13 with appDir